# Count lines of code on a Database field

Tags: php, mysql

Using PHP and MySQL.  I need to do something similar to how Github does when it shows source code,

`122 lines (98 sloc) 4.003 kb`

I need to get the total number of `Lines Of Code` and `Source Lines Of Code` from a MySQL database result.

The source code will be in a wordpress table as a meta field, I know how to accomplish this with a file, but not with a Database result.  I then need to also calculate the disk space used on this field to show something like `4.003 kb`

If you know how to do any of this, I would appreciate any help

### UPDATE

This very ugly code is the only solution I have found so far, if you search SO or Google, all the results show how to count lines of code on a FILE, my problem is very different, I am not fetching a file, I have a result from a MySQL database held in a $variable

This code below does 1 of the 3 things, it ets total number of lines of (LOC) so I would just need to get (SLOC) and (Disk space used) however I am very open to a better way of counting the LOC of a variable.

```
// Get LOC
$a = $code_source; // Variable holding our code
$result = count_chars($a, 0);
for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
    if ($result[$i] != 0) {
        if (chr($i) == "\n") // line feed
           $n = $result[$i];
        if (chr($i) == "\r") // carriage return
            $r = $result[$i];
    }
}
if ($n > $r) $l = $n + 1;
if ($r >= $n) $l = $r + 1;
if (!isset($l) ) $l = "2";

echo "Line Of Code = " . $l;
```

Space

```
//Get Disk Space Used
if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
    $size = mb_strlen($code_source, '8bit');
} else {
    $size = strlen($code_source);
}
if($size >= 1024)
    $size = round($size / 1024, 2).' KB';
else
    $size = $size.' bytes';
echo 'size of file' . ': ' . $size;
```

### 2nd Update

Ok here is the end result I have now, I omitted @refp's (LOC) code as I could not get it to work for some reason, I did use his SLOC code and put in all into a usable class.  Please fill free to improve

```
class SourceCodeHelper{

    // Count total number of Lines (LOC)
    public function countLOC($string){
        $result = count_chars($string, 0);
        for ($i=0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
            if ($result[$i] != 0) {
                if (chr($i) == "\n\n") // line feed
                   $n = $result[$i];
                if (chr($i) == "\r") // carriage return
                    $r = $result[$i];
            }
        }
        if ($n > $r) $l = $n + 1;
        if ($r >= $n) $l = $r + 1;
        if (!isset($l) ) $l = "2";
        //substr_count ($data, "\n") + 1;
        return  $l;
    }

    // Count total Source code lines of Code (SLOC)
    public function countSLOC($string){
        return count(preg_split("/\n\s*/", $string));
    }

    // Calculate disk space usage of string
    public function stringDiskSpace($string){
        if (function_exists('mb_strlen')) {
            $size = mb_strlen($string, '8bit');
        } else {
            $size = strlen($string);
        }
        return diskSpacePretty($size);
    }

    // Format a disk space usage into human readable format
    public function diskSpacePretty($size){
        if($size >= 1024)
            $size = round($size / 1024, 2).' KB';
        else
            $size = $size.' bytes';
        return $size;
    }
```

}

Comment: If the database field text has line breaks, then you should be able to run text analysis functions on the contents of the database field in the same way you would on the contents of a file, no?

Comment: how is sloc different from loc?

Comment: @chris I googled and it said LOC includes lines of code and empty lines and SLOC is just line with code, the above example is from Github

Comment: @jasondavis `substr_count ($data, "\n") + 1` is fully functional, though in `SourceCodeHelper::countLOC` the parameter is called `$string` and you are passing `$data` to substr_count, are you aware of this?

BTW: You should make the functions in SourceCodeHelper static, or put ever function in a namespace instead since there is no need to forcing developers creating an instance of SourceCodeHelper just to use the functions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no straight forward way of counting the number of lines in a field from the inside of mysql.

Instead I recommend you to append a new column to your table where you store the number of lines. Calculate the LOC/SLOC by using PHP (or whatever backend language is responsible for inserting data) and update it when neccessary.

---

To count the number of lines (LOC) in a string you can use [substr_count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php) which will count the number of occurrences of the second parameter string inside of the first one.

In the below example we will count how many times `\n` is present inside `$data`.

```
substr_count ($data, "\n") + 1; // since one \n creates two lines
```

---

To count the number of SLOC you can use [preg_split](http://se.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to filter off all empty lines (lines of length 0 or only containing white spaces)

```
count (preg_split ("/\n\s*/", $data))
```

Comment: Good idea, I wasn't sure how to count the lines though, the only way I have done it before is to use count() on an included files which puts each line into an array and can be counted, wasn't sure if there was a better way with the result when I fetch it at first

Comment: @jasondavis I provided you with methods of counting both LOC and SLOC, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, the following query should be able to count the number of lines in a field. However its a bit hacky and i doubt it will scale well! All depends on your use case i guess.

```
SELECT 
  SUM( LENGTH(fieldname) - LENGTH(REPLACE(fieldname, '\n', ''))+1) 
FROM tablename
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Hi actually I already fetch the result, it is part of a wordpress query so I have the result in a variable, I need to somehow get the LOC on a variable.  The variable is a string wrapped in  `<pre>` tags

Comment: In that case it looks like @refp might have given you what you need.

Comment: @leenix what a beautiful hack! I didn't even think of that one, great job. Yes, I've provided him with methods of calculating both LOC and SLOC (in PHP).

Comment: I'll update my post with something that might work, I was looking for help in how to code it, not the theory and that is what he provided